# Recover tokens from a contract

Tags: contract-design, gas

So, Account A has Tokens that I want to transfer out but whenever I transfer ETH to Account A it automatically transfer my ETH out to another address and I know you can't change private key, any idea how I can get my ERC-20 Token out from Account A? Really appreciate if someone can help me out

Answer (score 1):

I think you are actually trying to withdraw a token that doesn't belong to you.
I know there are some random guys posting private keys of a wallet containing some erc20 tokens and when you try to access and "steal" the tokens by sending eth for gas, the eth is automatically transfered to another wallet belonging to the scammers.

Comment: There was the case a famous wallet will generate an account with private key equal to the sha3 of the password. And the default password was empty, so lots of people ended up with the same address. At first there's issue because you see the tokens in your account, but you will be unable to move them.

Comment: @Ismael this particular case is currently trending on reddit. There is a wallet with lots of ICX and another with lots of Minereum tokens. The scammer pretends to be careless with their private keys by posting it on various telegram groups. The address automatically sweeps any eth that is sent (to pay for gas)  to another wallet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deposit some ETH for contract gas spending.
No way if ETH of Account is Zero or very little which not enough GAS spending.

Comment: totally understood but the problem is everytime ETH is deposited it gets automatically withdrawn out to another address

Answer (score 0):

Your description implies that Account A is a contract. It would not be able to automatically do anything unless this was the case.

You cannot recover the tokens unless the contract has a function to accomplish it. That is, contracts can't do things they weren't designed to do, and they can't be patched.

There is an outside chance that the contract implements functionality to recover tokens stored there. For example, open-zeppelin's `CanReclaimTokens` logic. In such a case, you would send a transaction to Account A instructing it to forward your tokens. If Account A was provided by an online service, it's possible they can help you, if they anticipated this scenario.

It might be a good exploration to disassemble the bytecode at Address A to see if there is a promising-looking function. If you can't find one, you're probably hooped. Unless there is a function to deal with this scenario, your tokens could be marooned in the contract.

You can find the contract bytecode by looking up Account A with https://etherscan.io. They have a tool to assist with disassembling the code here: https://etherscan.io/opcode-tool.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi there I dont think so it is a contract or anything that looks similar to any ERC-20 ICOs (pardon me if im wrong), or maybe that person who's holding my wallet's private key possibly made a bot to transfer any ETH deposited, to another account is that possible? I tried alot of stuff for the past few months and saw a few posts that people are making a contract to pay fees with ERC20-Token this year so still waiting for that